# is missing required Java project:'appcompat_v7'

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

Found this error after importing a application from ADT:

```
is missing required Java project:'appcompat_v7'
```

My project.properties doesn't contains 'appcompat_v7.
Only:

```
target=android-20
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

appcompat_v7 is a library-project for Android 4.0+ themes.

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android

Check if the project appcompat_v7 is checked.

[image]

Comment: There aren't what you say.

Comment: If you don`t have the libraries, you must install via android sdk. This link will guide you
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#